# Prevent customized bash autocomplete from affecting io redirection (< and >)

Tags: bash, io-redirection, autocomplete

I've used `complete -W 'firstdatabase databasetwo etc' mysql` to save a list of databases, so that I can autocomplete them using the `mysql` command.

However, in many cases I would type `mysql db < /tmp/script.sql`. How can I get bash to revert to traditional autocomplete (filenames) after seeing the first `>` or `<`?

---

**Update:** I pulled up a stock Ubuntu install, which comes with the [bash-autocomplete](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package pre-installed. While simply installing that same package on our server is not an option for me, I can still learn from its implementation by examining the output of `complete -p` and `declare`. (`alias -p` has some cool stuff as well)

On our server, I used `complete -d cd`. I observe that it suffers from the same issue in that after `<` or `>`, the `complete -d` functionality persists. However, [bash-autocomplete](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) has a more elaborate approach which solves this issue. Learning how they solved it for `cd` (and a multitude of other commands) may show how to solve the same issue I'm having for `mysql`.

So, here is their implementation for `cd`: They use `complete -o nospace -F _cd cd`, which basically calls function `_cd` for the autocomplete query. Here is the function they use:

```
_cd ()
{ 
    local cur prev words cword;
    _init_completion || return;
    local IFS='
' i j k;
    compopt -o filenames;
    if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then
        _filedir -d;
        return 0;
    fi;
    local -r mark_dirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-directories && echo y);
    local -r mark_symdirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-symlinked-directories && echo y);
    for i in ${CDPATH//:/'
'};
    do
        k="${#COMPREPLY[@]}";
        for j in $( compgen -d $i/$cur );
        do
            if [[ ( -n $mark_symdirs && -h $j || -n $mark_dirs && ! -h $j ) && ! -d ${j#$i/} ]]; then
                j+="/";
            fi;
            COMPREPLY[k++]=${j#$i/};
        done;
    done;
    _filedir -d;
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        i=${COMPREPLY[0]};
        if [[ "$i" == "$cur" && $i != "*/" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY[0]="${i}/";
        fi;
    fi;
    return 0
}

complete -o nospace -F _cd cd
```

Running the above code on a recent version of `bash` gives the desired results for `cd`. Now how can this be converted for `mysql`? (or anything I'd normally use `complete -W` for?)

Comment: It's not obvious to me how this code works, but I'll figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is in the `_init_completion` function which is defined in the [`bash_completion` file of the bash-completion package](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion).

There's no easy way out. If you want sensible fancy completion in bash, install the bash-completion package. Then define a function:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
_my_mysql () {
  local cur prev words cword
  _init_completion || return
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W 'firstdatabase databasetwo etc' "$cur"))
}
complete -F _my_mysql mysql
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. For some reason I missed the fact that the `_cd` function didn't work by itself. I tried to install bash-completion, but the build failed on my server. I may try harder later. Thanks for the example `_my_mysql` function. This should save me some time once I get this stuff worked out because I imagine I'm going to have a lot more customizations moving forward. :-)

Comment: Next thing I try will probably be to copy the finished autocomplete files from Ubuntu, and skip the `make` step altogether.